# What are the Steps to install WAS 9.0 using command line?

Tags: websphere

Can some one help me with the steps to install WAS 9.0 using command line on windows. I am upgrading my WAS from 8.5.5.0 to 9.0 and i have migrate profiles, configuration etc from 8.5.5.0 to 9.0. I have researched alot online but without any help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From an installation point of view, you cannot "update" or "upgrade" from WAS v8.5.5 to v9.0 -- They are separate installations.

You will need to install WAS v9.0 separately using IBM Installation Manager.  Then, migrate your profiles and applications over.  I am assuming we are talking about WAS traditional here.

You can find instructions on how to install WAS v9.0 (using command line) in IBM's Knowledge Center at [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/welc6topinstalling.html).

Comment: Thank you Ykchang for your help! I will go through the instruction in the article.